# Dereferencing syntax in copy constructor for class that contains other objects

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, composition, copy-constructor

Suppose the class *MyClass* has constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass( ... ) {
    var = new OtherClass( ... );
}
```

and suppose the class *OtherClass* has copy constructor:

```
OtherClass::OtherClass(const OtherClass &obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
        array[i] = obj.array[i];
    }
}
```

Is the below a recommended way to write the copy constructor for MyClass?

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &obj) {
    var = new OtherClass(*obj.var);
}
```

I'm asking because I haven't been able to find an example of the dereferencing syntax the above copy constructor uses.

**Edit:** I'm sorry, I left a typo in the copy constructor (introduced while I was trying to make the code example abstract): `*obj.array` was intended to be `*obj.var`.

Comment: what is the type of `MyClass::array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesn't really make sense.  What makes sense is this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &obj) {
    var = new OtherClass(*obj.var);
}
```

Or rather:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &obj)
    :var(new OtherClass(*obj.var))
{}
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the typo. The first part of your suggestion uses the syntax I had intended to use, but I hadn't considered using the member initialization list. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `var` is actually a member of MyClass and a pointer to `OtherClass`, I would write

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &obj) : var(new OtherClass(obj.array))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's generally recommended that copy ctors take `const` reference parameters.

You do not need to dereference a reference.  Change your code to:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &obj) {
    var = new OtherClass(obj.array);
}
```

Comment: -1: Not using the copy constructor of OtherClass (var not array)

Comment: @Martin:  The copt ctor I was referring to is `MyClass`'s

Comment: So why not use the OtherClass copy constructor?

Comment: Sorry about the typo (`obj.array` rather than `obj.var`)--which unfortunately is copied in the above response. Since `obj.var` is a pointer, and the `OtherClass` copy constructor expects an object (of which it creates a const reference), I believe I have to dereference `obj.var`.